# I want to make on click listener stop when on touch listener is working

Tags: android

I am making chat head and I want to make on click listener stop when on touch listener is working because when on touch listener is working on click listener is working to so it open window

My code :

On Click Listener

```
  chatHead.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

}

}
```

On Touch Listener

```
chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {






              private int initialX;
              private int initialY;
              private float initialTouchX;
              private float initialTouchY;

              @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {





                  if (on.equals("true"))
                  {
                      params.x = 0;
                        params.y = 0;


                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params); 
                  }



                switch (event.getAction()) {
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                   initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                   initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                     // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return false;

                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                   params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);

                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);



                    return false;


                }
                return false;
              }
        });
      }
```

Edit :

You know Facebook messenger chat head when you move the chat head it moves with you and when you click on it it opens i am making chat head like Facebook chat head but when i move it it move but also it opens while moving so i want to separate on click from on touch like Facebook so when it move i never opens

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is

```
int open ;



Image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

if ( open < 10)
{
do it
}
}
}











case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

open++;

return false;




switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

open=0;
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `setOnClickListener(null);` ?

Comment: when i set this
chatHead.setOnClickListener(null);
in in touch Listerine 
the on click listener not working any more

Comment: Wasn't it the point of your question ? Disable the OnClickListener ?

Comment: No i want to disable on click listener when on touch listener is work and when on touch listener isn't work on click listener work again

Comment: then use setOnClickListener(null) at the begining and setOnClickListener(this) at the end.

Comment: Doesn't work it gives an error 

         chatHead.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnTouchListener(){})

Comment: You know Facebook messenger chat head when you move the chat head it moves with you and when you click on it it opens i am making chat head like Facebook chat head but when i move it it move but also it opens while moving so i want to separate on click from on touch like Facebook so when it move i never opens

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried return `true` inside `onTouch()` when your `OnTouchListener` consumed the event?

Update:
As far as I understand what your code does, I think when in `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, you should return `true`.

Comment: You know Facebook messenger chat head when you move the chat head it moves with you and when you click on it it opens i am making chat head like Facebook chat head but when i move it it move but also it opens while moving so i want to separate on click from on touch like Facebook so when it move i never opens

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance member in ChatHead class, boolean bFireOnClick; when onTouch is handled by your app you could just do

```
bFireOnClick = false;
```

and in OnClick listener

```
if(bFireOnClick){
 bFireOnClick = false;
 return; 

}
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer

Comment: You know Facebook messenger chat head when you move the chat head it moves with you and when you click on it it opens i am making chat head like Facebook chat head but when i move it it move but also it opens while moving so i want to separate on click from on touch like Facebook so when it move i never opens

Comment: Okay, well all I wanted to say was that in some cases you will be doing something inside your OnTouch logic and sometimes you will not do anything and let OnClick take care of the touch event. Right?
All I am trying to say, just use a binary flag here.
Define a boolean variable inside you ChatHead class and set it to true when you do something with the touch event. When you don't do anything to the touch event, you could set it to false and in that case onclick could act.

Answer (score 0):

When you returning `false` within `OnTouchListener`, it will allow `OnClickListener` to handle clicks. If you returning `true` within `OnTouchListener`, it will not allow other events to trigger at same time. So within your `OnTouchListener` try to return `true` if you don't want to handle `click` and `touch` events at same time.

```
chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

              private int initialX;
              private int initialY;
              private float initialTouchX;
              private float initialTouchY;

              @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                  if (on.equals("true"))
                  {
                      params.x = 0;
                        params.y = 0;


                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params); 
                  }

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                   initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                   initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                     // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return true;

                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                   params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);

                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);

                   return true;
                    }
                return true;
              }
        });
      }
```

Comment: No i want to disable on click listener when on touch listener is work and when on touch listener isn't work on click listener work again

Comment: returning `true` will avoid `onClickListener` to work, did you tried with `return true`

Comment: I want them both to work but what i want is make onclick lisner dosent work when i am moving the chat head

Comment: sorry i can not understand what you are needed.

Comment: I making chat head application i want when i move chat head all over the screen the on click listener stops

but when i doesn't move the chat head the on click works

Comment: You know Facebook messenger chat head when you move the chat head it moves with you and when you click on it it opens

 i am making chat head like Facebook chat head but when i move it it move but also it opens while moving so i want to separate on click from on touch like Facebook so when it move i never opens